# What is the difference between parallax and disparity

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, stereoscopy

i've been learning about stereoscopic 3d lately and there is one thing that is not so clear to me. What is the difference between parallax and disparity.

I have the feeling that both terms are being used interchangeably.

**Example definitions:**

Binocular disparity refers to the difference in image location of an object seen by the left and right eyes, resulting from the eyes’ horizontal separation.

The distance between left and right
corresponding image points (sometimes also called “homologous” or
“conjugate” points) is parallax, and may be measured in inches or
millimeters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Disparity" (usually in "disparity map") is a computed estimate of the parallax as observed in an image pair.

Comment: Ah i think i understood. Parallax is the distance difference between two corresponding points on the image...and this difference translates in disparity on the raetinae which in turn gives the depth feeling when the two images are combined on the brain (or at least that is how i understood it )

Comment: Easier: parallax is optics, it exists "out there", disparity is what you (or the computer) think of it :-)